# Silverlight 4 Stack panel - animating child when item removed

Tags: animation, silverlight-4.0, stackpanel

I want to modify a stack panel, so when an item is removed from it all the items under it slides in animation upwards to fill the missing gap. what is the approach I need to take in order to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ListBox instead, and have its ItemsPanel be a StackPanel. Then, modify the style of the items to include an animation in AfterLoaded, BeforeLoaded, and BeforeUnloaded visual states.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798276.aspx